# Sonatype Nexus: Cannot proxy http://milton.io/maven/

Tags: maven, proxy, nexus, milton

We are using Nexus to proxy remote maven repositories.
It works well except with the maven repository of milton.io.

If I add the repository to my maven settings.xml without using Nexus it works well, artifacts are correctly pulled:

```
<repository>
   <id>milton-repo</id>
   <url>http://milton.io/maven/</url>
</repository>
```

Now if I use Nexus adding the repository as a 'Proxy repository' it does not work. Nexus cannot pull the required artifacts:

```
Failure to find io.milton:milton-server-ce:jar:2.6.4.0 in http://xxx:8180/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Any idea why Nexus cannot proxy this repository ?

EDIT: If I look in Nexus log if have this:

```
2015-03-17 11:05:05,779+0100 INFO  [ar-4-thread-4] admin org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.routing.internal.RemoteScrapeStrategy - Not possible remote scrape of M2Repository(id=milton), no scraper succeeded.
```

Note: the proxy repository has correctly been added to the public group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing extremely poor performance from this server, this request took nearly a minute to process:

http://milton.io/maven/io/milton/milton-server-ce/2.6.4.0/milton-server-ce-2.6.4.0.jar

So you're likely hitting the repository's default read timeout of 20 seconds in Nexus.

Check the nexus.log file to see if there are timeout exceptions.  If there are, then increase the timeout in "http request settings (optional)" in the repository's configuration.  A timeout of 60 seconds with 3 retries seems like it might work.

Comment: Yes at some point yesterday it had poor performance but when I tried it was quick. Tried again today and the requests are quick, but I'm still having problems to proxy the repository in Nexus.